# XML Root element error

Tags: xml

I have an error in my XML file.

The error list says:

> "Application Configuration file "App.config" is invalid. The
>   'configuration' start tag on line 3 position 2 does not match the end
>   tag of 'rootElement'. Line 25, position 7."

Comment: What's the question? Can you show the indicated lines?

Comment: You are missing lines at end of file.  The tags must be balanced for each <root> you need a </root>.